# {NodeJS} How to stock Token API from HTTP Request (Post)

Tags: node.js, api, discord, discord.js

I'm here for looking help, I'm new on NodeJS and I would like to creat a Discord Bot.

I'm currently using(npm) Discord.Js & Http; I have succefully creat a http post request for getting my api token :

```
const infos = JSON.stringify({ grant_type: "password", username: "arius", password: "myanwsomepwd" });
const options = {
  hostname: 'arius.freeboxos.fr',
  port: 5500,
  path: '/api/oauth/token',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': infos.length
  }};

const req = http.request(options, res => {
  res.on('data', d => {
    process.stdout.write(d)
    const MParse = JSON.parse(d)
    const MyToken = MParse.access_token
  })
});

req.on('error', error => {
  console.error(error)
});
req.write(infos)
req.end()
```

This return correctly all my needed informations, but I would like to save/stock this token (MyToken) for using it on a GET Request :

```
  const options = {
    hostname: 'arius.freeboxos.fr',
    port: 5500,
    path: '/api/v1/info',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${MyToken}`
    }};
  
    const req = http.request(options, res => {
      console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
    
      res.on('data', d => {
        process.stdout.write(d)
      })
    })
    
    req.on('error', error => {
      console.error(error)
    })
    
    req.end()
```

I know  " 'Authorization': `Bearer ${MyToken}` " is bad typed it's just for explain the goal of the request. (I don't want actually using a Database or external files for save this token)

My index.js :

```
const discord = require('discord.js')
const ping = require('./commands/ping')
const suppr = require('./commands/suppr')
// const authapi = require('./commands/authapi')
const apisinfos = require('./api/info')
const clients = new discord.Client()
clients.login('MyAnwsomeDiscordBotToken')
clients.once('ready', () => { 
    console.log('All right !')
})


clients.on('message', message => {
    ping.parse(message) ||
    suppr.parse(message) ||
  //  authapi.parse(message) ||
    apisinfos.parse(message)
})
```

My api/cmds.js class :

```
module.exports = class Cmds {
static parse (message) {
  if (this.match(message)) {
    this.action(message)
    return true
  }
  return false
}

static match (message) {
  return false
}

static action (message) {
}}
```

infos.js :

```
const Cmds = require('./cmds')
const http = require('http')
 
module.exports = class Apisinfo extends Cmds {
 
    static match (message) {
        return message.content.startsWith('!api-info')
    }
 
    static action (message) {
      const infos = JSON.stringify({ grant_type: "password", username: "arius", password: "AnwsomePassword" });
      const options = {
        hostname: 'arius.freeboxos.fr',
        port: 5500,
        path: '/api/oauth/token',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Content-Length': infos.length
        }};
       
      const req = http.request(options, res => {
        res.on('data', d => {
          process.stdout.write(d)
          const MParse = JSON.parse(d)
          const tok = MParse.access_token
        })
      });
       
      req.on('error', error => {
        console.error(error)
      });
      req.write(infos)
      req.end()
  }
}
```

Thanks for the read <3 !

Comment: Are you trying to send the GET request immediately after you obtain the token? In that case you can store the token at a higher scope so it can be accessed from outside the http.request() function.

Comment: Hello,
All my code is running good ( and have changing a lot ). On this part : 

const req = http.request(options, res => { 

res.on('data', d => { 
const Token = JSON.parse(d).access_token
// Here my " const Token " get correctly the result.
})
// here I can't get back my ${Token} || Normal Out of the function
})
// here I can't get back my ${Token} || Normal Out of the function
....

There are a way to get back this Value, or I need to continue the code logic in this fonction ?